# Cloudwatch logs to Elastic Search service configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have configured my elastic beanstalk environment to forward logs to Cloudwatch.
That seems to work, I can see the logs in the cloudwatch service.

I setup a ElasticSearch cluster and it was successful and status shows active.

However, when I try to forward the logs in cloudwatch to ElasticSearch service, I get an error saying the following.

Warning
This Amazon Elasticsearch Service cluster is not active yet. This setup needs your cluster to be in Active state.

[image: Error in Cloudwatch when I select "Stream to ElasticSearch domain"]

As you can see below, my elastic search cluster is in active status.

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I configured AWS-ES within a VPC. Don't see this with public access. So I guess I wasn't using the right VPC.

I am going with public access for now for PoC and later will come back to locking it down.